# PayMill subscription interval regularity

Tags: date, intervals, subscription, payment-processing, paymill

Simple questions, but I can't seem to find the answers in PayMill's API documentation or FAQ:

1. If a payment subscription is classed as monthly, does it poll for the funds every 30 days or on the anniversary of the month, i.e. set up on 15.4.2014, next payment 15.5.2014?
2. If it polls on the same date every month, what happens if the subscription was set up on the 31st of the month, i.e. on a date not present in February, April etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the same date. If the interval is 1 MONTH and the first payment occurs on 15.4.2014 the next one will be on 15.5.2014. Note that you can also specify a weekday, in that case it will be the next weekday (e.g. Monday), either the 15.05.2014 (if it's a Monday) or the first Monday after 15.05.2014
2. It will **probably** be on the next day (1 March instead of the "missing 31 February". It will definitely not be skipped.  If the exact behavior is crucial for your business, please contact the PAYMILL support to seek a definite answer.